# How to export 2 page spread as single pages in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I purchased an InDesign template, and it has a 2 page spread:

[image]

I want to export to PDF with a width of 1 page, rather than retaining the 2 page width.

How do I do this?

I am happy to change to single page layout in InDesign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if your template is set up as a "Facing pages" document, meaning you see it as spreads, you can export this as "Single pages", just make sure you have the "Spreads" checkbox set to 'off' in the pdf export dialog below.

You don't need to change the actual template to achieve this, its just an export setting.

[image: indesign pdf export dialog]